# Make: Dependency on newest file in directory

Tags: makefile, dependencies

For a small project, I have the following workflow:

1. compile code and generate `./data` and `./images`
2. run code, which will write many files to `./data`
3. generate  images from the data files, place them in `./images`
4. generate a video from the images

I have written a makefile, which can run the code, and compile it before, if necessary. But I don't know how to implement the dependencies of steps 3 and 4, and currently make that targets manually.

So, is there a way to check if e.g. the newest file in `./data` is newer than the newest file in `./images` ? It's not necessary to do this on a file-by-file basis, and the total number of data / image files is not known.

Comment: "It's not necessary to do this on a file-by-file basis" Why not? Is there not a one-to-one correspondence between the files in `data` and `images`?

Answer (score 1):

Typically the date of the directory is the date that the last file was added/modified, so you could use the timestamp on the directory itself for dependencies.

```
images : data
     // generate images
```

Alternatively, if there is a mapping between the files in the two directories, you could do something like:

```
images/%.img: data/%.dat
    // generate image...
```

which would prevent reprocessing data that's already been handled.

Comment: Note, that directory timestamp is only changed on file addition and removal. When you change the contents of existing files the directory timestamp does not change.